# $k$-th order autocorrelation of a squared ARCH(1) process

Tags: time-series, self-study, autocorrelation, garch

I want to derive that in ARCH(1) model, $\operatorname{Corr}(y_t^2,y_{t-k}^2)=\alpha^k$. Could you please take a look at to the photo attached and help me on how to proceed:

[image: photo is here]

Comment: Hi Neda. This is a MathJax enabled site. You can use this for formatting the equations in your post. For help, check [Instructions on how to use LaTeX on CrossValidated](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1604/instructions-on-how-to-use-latex-on-crossvalidated).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key here is to notice that in the formulation
$$
y_t^2 = \omega + \alpha y_{t-1}^2 + \xi_t
$$
the $\xi_t$ terms have some convenient properties:

1. $\mathbb{E}(\xi_t)=0$ for all $t$
2. $\mathrm{Cov}(\xi_t, \xi_{t-k})=0$ for all $k \neq 0$
3. $\mathrm{Cov}(\xi_t, y_{t-k})=0$ for $k=1,2,\ldots$

This means that we can treat $\left\{y_t^2\right\}$ as an AR(1) process, and the autocorrelation result follows naturally.

Comment: Many thanks Doctor Milt! With your guidance, I could derive the Corr :)

Comment: Great! I'm glad I could help.